# Element doesn't appear in IE7 until I edit it through Developer Toolbar

Tags: internet-explorer-7

This one has me stumped - I have an element on my page with an absolute position, inside of a container with a relative position. In all browsers except IE7, it appears in the correct spot with no issues at all.

In IE7, the element doesn't appear until I *add or edit any of its CSS properties* in the Attributes tab of the Developer Toolbar (even properties that have nothing to do with its visibility or position, like `color`). Once I do so, it then appears correctly - and even remains visible if I delete the property that I just added (or undo the modification)!

This must be an IE7-specific display bug, but I can't figure out a way around it - I've thrown `float`, `zoom`, etc. at it to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by moving the disappearing element one level deeper, into another child element. Since the child element is floated, but does not have a position, the disappearing element is still positioned relative to the parent element, which is what I want - but for some reason this also causes it to be visible in IE7, like it's supposed to be.

This is what I had that caused the element to disappear (not the real IDs):

```
<div id="parent" style="position: relative;">
  <div id="disappear" style="position: absolute; left: -8px; top: -17px;>This element disappears</div>
</div>
```

This is what makes it appear:

```
<div id="parent" style="position: relative;">
  <div id="child" style="float: left; width: 340px;">
    <div id="disappear" style="position: absolute; left: -8px; top: -17px;">Now this element appears</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Floating `#parent` and giving it a `width` (the same two properties that `#child` has) didn't work, though - I have to use a separate child element. Totally bizarre, but figured I'd post this in case anyone else runs into the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it weird how IE developer tool bar triggers it to be visible?!

I fixed it by instead of using absolute positioning for the child element using relative positioning with a negative margin-left to position the element. Not ideal as it makes the design more fragile, but my only option at the time.