# internet explorer 10 not showing svg path (d3.js graph)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, d3.js, internet-explorer-10

If I open this graph for example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292
in IE10, i just can't see the links between the nodes.

Is there anything I can do in the code to make it possible to see even with Internet Explorer?

It seems IE just ignore some pieces of the svg... I couldn't find any way to make it visible.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it in IE10? What does the error console say? Are the path nodes there and in the svg namespace? Are they containing properly formatted path data?

Comment: How do i debug in IE?

Comment: Press F12, or choose "F12 developer tools" from the popup menu after pressing the tools icon in the upper right corner of IE10.  Then choose the "Script" tag and press the "Start debugging" button in the new window that opens up.  (This is using Windows 7.)

Comment: This issue is also for IE 11

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Summary:**

There is a [bug in IE](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/781964/) that causes paths with markers to render improperly. The original code [with markers removed](http://jsfiddle.net/niaconis/3YsWY/8/) renders without problem.

There are three solutions:

1. Don't use markers
2. Embed the markers in the path like this: http://jsfiddle.net/niaconis/3YsWY/9/
3. Wait for Microsoft to fix this bug

Option 2, though a little ugly, is probably the most viable.

---

**Original post:**

Unfortunately, I've found James' answer only works for the static svg.

I pulled the css and javascript from the original example and placed them in jsfiddle. The links displayed correctly in Chrome 26 (this was my sort of control test), but didn't display at all in IE 10 (as expected). I then edited the javascript which dealt with the creation of the links according to the answer James gave:

```
var path = svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return "none"; }) /*new*/
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return "1.5px"; }) /*new*/
    .attr("stroke", function(d) { return "#666"; }) /*new*/
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });
```

This did add the specified attributes to the `<g>` element, but had no effect on the display of the "live" graph. (Checking back now, I've noticed the "static" graph displays links in IE10 even without these attributes as seen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jgHft).)

I was able to make the links visible in IE10 (even directly in the [original example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292)) by using IE's developer toolbar. I found one of the `<path>` tags in the DOM, then in the Style tab to the right unchecked and rechecked the "path.link" style.

This gets the links to show, but any subsequent interaction with the graph disconnects the markers from the ends of the links. They simply stay in place, and I've found nothing that will get them to re-attach.

The only source of information I can find that seems relevant is this SO post: [Element doesn't appear in IE7 until I edit it through Developer Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714340/element-doesnt-appear-in-ie7-until-i-edit-it-through-developer-toolbar)
However, I'm fairly new to svg, so I haven't the slightest idea how to port the fix described there to svg (that fix was for an html element)

Maybe this will help someone get headed in the right direction?

P.S. I know this isn't exactly an answer, and I would have just posted this as a reply to James' answer, but it seems I don't have enough reputation to do that. =\

---

**Update:**

As it turns out, this issue is related entirely to markers. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niaconis/3YsWY/8/) is the original code but with markers removed, and the links show up just fine. The marker issue has been [documented before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693178/svg-line-markers-not-updating-when-line-moves-in-ie10) and is a serious bug of IE10. Why it also causes the links to disappear, I don't know.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niaconis/3YsWY/9/) offers a work-around. It's not the cleanest solution as I've encoded each marker directly in its link's path, but it works.

If anyone can find a work-around for the marker issue itself, that would be better, and it should additionally be posted as an answer to the [other marker question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693178/svg-line-markers-not-updating-when-line-moves-in-ie10).

(Also note: My solution makes dashed links look terrible, so I've made them light blue instead.)

This bug has been reported to Microsoft, but so far they seem to have [denied or ignored](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/f772aab3-5ce3-4367-8eec-4fe58ad94b14/) it. Please go to [this post](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/781964/) on Microsoft's issue tracker website and click the link indicating you can reproduce this bug. Maybe we can get their attention?

Comment: I don't know about the OP, but this was certainly useful for me. And with the amount of information you've provided, it's better as a separate answer anyway, because there's a limit to what you can put in the comments. +1

Comment: I happened to find a solution that works... somewhat. Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niaconis/3YsWY/1/embedded/result/). It still has the disembodied marker issue, but the links are visible.  (Also, to James, I'm glad the information will be useful. I didn't know there was a limit since I hadn't had the opportunity to comment before.)

Comment: I don't currently have access to a system with IE10, and I can never get javascript to work with NetRenderer which is why I've been testing with static markup. But since the problem seems to be js related, based on your findings, that explains why I can't reproduce it. Unfortunately it also means I can't confirm your solution.

Comment: @codefox421: This looks promising, thank you. If only the arrows could be attached to the edges I will gladly award the bounty.

Comment: @mareser: I've managed to get something resembling what it should be. Check my updated answer for the work-around.

Comment: @codefox421: Your [workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/niaconis/3YsWY/9/) is amazing, thanks a lot for helping. Enjoy the bounty!

Comment: @codefox421 This is fantastic. I'm trying to do the same for straight lines with markers in the middle of the line, but the "magic" numbers in some of your formulas seem to be for aligning with arcs and I can't tease it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @dan-bailiff Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/niaconis/3YsWY/16/) of putting square markers in the middle of straight lines. The formulas it uses should be a little easier to digest. Let me know if it helps you out.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to come up with a very similar solution on my own, once I had knocked the rust of my trigonometry skills!

Comment: @codefox421 Great workaround! I tried changing the circle radius by replacing all instances of 6 with a variable but it seems to break the arrow position and orientation. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The [other marker question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693178/svg-line-markers-not-updating-when-line-moves-in-ie10) has an excellent answer by Christian Lund which worked for me very well.

To save you the trouble of going there, here's the gist of things:

In my force animation, I have a `tick` function that looks like this:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
  ...
});
```

I also hold all of my graph links inside the `link` variable, defined like so:

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link").data(links).enter() ...
```

Now, to implement the magic suggested by Christian, I've added this line in the beginning of my `tick` function:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
  link.each(function() {this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this); });
  ...
});
```

I left all of my markers intact. What this little piece of wonder does, is go over all the link nodes every tick of the animation, and re-add them to the DOM. This causes IE 10 to re-render them, and all is good with the world.

This seems to fix the IE 10 problems... of course it's recommended to add this patch only on IE 10

If this works for you don't forget to go to the other question and give Christian an upvote

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this has been resolved already, but the graph looks almost identical to me in all the browsers I've compared. I don't have IE10, but it looks fine in IE9 and I tested a static copy of the graph on [NetRenderer's](http://netrenderer.com/index.php) IE10 and that looked fine too.

The only difference I could see is that IE didn't show solid arrow heads for some of the links, and that could easily be resolved just by setting the fill styles for those marker types.

```
marker#suit {
  fill: black;
}
marker#resolved {
  fill: black;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Looking at the images you've added, that's definitely not what I'm seeing in IE9 or NetRenderer's version of IE10. Have you tried on multiple computers? Is it perhaps something specific to your setup?

It's difficult to make suggestions without being able to reproduce the problem, but one thing you might want to try, is setting the path properties directly in the SVG rather than via the CSS.

So on the first `g` element you would have something like this:

```
<g fill="none" stroke-width="1.5px" stroke="#666">
```

Here's a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iAwoG) using a static version of the markup. And here's the [fullpage url](http://codepen.io/anon/fullpage/iAwoG) if you want to test it in NetRenderer yourself.

Even if that's not an ideal solution, it would at least be helpful to know whether that makes any difference.