# SVG line markers not updating when line moves in IE10?

Tags: html, svg, internet-explorer-10

I have some SVG lines with line markers on them, and I have a script that moves those lines around. This works fine on all browsers, including IE9.

However, I just tried it on IE10, and the line markers get left behind when the line moves.

An example of this can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/swYRK/8/

I have tried this on both Windows 7 and 8.

Anyone know what's going on? Is this an IE10 bug, or is there another way to move the line and markers?

(Note the actual application is very performance sensitive, so I very much want to avoid doing something like re-creating the lines every frame while I move them, or something.)

```
-
```

Edit: this seems like a real IE 10 bug. I've found one [open issue in the IE bug tracker](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/781964/) (which requires a Microsoft account to even see, which makes it not visible to Google. Hello?), which I have added information to. IE has yet to accept the issue.

If there are any other work-arounds that people can think of, that would be great to hear. Completely removing the end markers, rendering that, and then re-adding them works-ish (shows visible flashing), but would not be acceptable in [my application](http://lab.dev.concord.org/examples/interactives/embeddable.html#interactives/sam/gas-laws/2-what-is-pressure.json), unfortunately.

Comment: Ideas (untested; I don't have IE10): if you change the position via setAttribute instead of the DOM, does it work? Can you apply a `transform="translate()"` and modify that instead? Can you wrap each line in a `<g>` that you translate, and does that result in it being dirty? What if after you change the values you place a big rectangle over or behind all content (or overlapping the bounding box of the old and new locations) to force a redraw.

Comment: Using setAttribute gives the exact same results. Using translate, either on the line or the lines own <g>, seems like a really complicated way to manipulate a line that's going to keep moving between arbitrary points, as I'd have to keep calculating a rotation, stretch, etc. Here's the actual use-case: http://short.concord.org//1a. In IE10, all the arrow heads get "left behind" once the arrows start moving

Comment: Of course; I did not consider that you were moving the end points individually. `transform` is thus right out. How about changing properties of either the markers, or swapping out the marker attributes on the line, after changing.

Comment: Wow, it's even weirder. If I change the markers (e.g. swap them), they move with the line. If I swap them and swap them right back again... they get left behind. It seems that if IE doesn't force an actual re-rendering of them when they swap the first time, it just completely ignores them when they swap twice in succession. So it may be tricky to get this to work in such a way that doesn't cause the markers to visibly flash or something. Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swYRK/10/

Comment: Just tested this on IE11 preview, still has this bug, by the way.

Comment: Yes, this was marked as WontFix by the IE team. They essentially said "we can replicate the bug, but we don't care about it." https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/781964/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a quick way of doing it, that works well. 
I have not noticed any flickering or performance related issues.

Simply re-add the svg node in it's original place:

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10") != -1) {
    svgNode.parentNode.insertBefore(svgNode, svgNode);
}
```

Of course, you could use any browser sniffing of choice..

Comment: +1 but need to update this for IE 11 too :(  They still haven't fixed it.

Comment: @RobertLevy You can tell M$ [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/781964/). Click the "I can too" button to tell them you can reproduce.

Comment: @styfle they've closed the issue and the following duplicate as not repairable. I really hope to live times that IE/EDGE would be just a bad memory

Comment: Fixed for IE11 for Windows 10, but not for IE11 on Windows 7. Both systems with all Windows Updates up to date. Just finished testing...

Answer (score 18):

I want to elaborate a little on the amazing answer given by @ChristianLund and how I used it successfully in my code

In my force animation, I have a `tick` function that looks like this:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
  ...
});
```

I also hold all of my graph links inside the `link` variable, defined like so:

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link").data(links).enter() ...
```

Now, to implement the magic suggested by Christian, I've added this line in the beginning of my `tick` function:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
  link.each(function() {this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this); });
  ...
});
```

This seems to fix the IE 10 problems... of course it's recommended to add this patch only on IE 10

Comment: Excellent job @talkol  !!  this solution save my life :)  great

Comment: Were you sent from heaven?

Answer (score 1):

In ie10/11, I found that the line does not move when it with marker-start/marker-end atrribute, I tried to remove those atrributes in your example, and it works. So the idea is remove the atrributes before set the x/y, then reset the atrributes after all jobs done.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this hack:

```
$("#button4").click(function () {
$("#line1")[0].setAttributeNS(null, "x1", 50);
$("#line1")[0].setAttributeNS(null, "y1", 50);
$("#line1")[0].setAttributeNS(null, "x2", 150);
$("#line1")[0].setAttributeNS(null, "y2", 50);
var oldAttValueDisplay = $("#line1")[0].getAttributeNS(null, "display");
$("#line1")[0].setAttributeNS(null, "display", "none");
setTimeout(function() {$("#line1")[0].setAttributeNS(null, "display", oldAttValueDisplay);}, 0);
// static: setTimeout(function() {$("#line1")[0].setAttributeNS(null, "display", "block");}, 0);
```

});