# How to render links as elbow connectors in d3 force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm very new to D3 and this is what I have done till now [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gj2y87z8/13/).

The actual code is over here:

```
var width = 1840,
    height = 1480,
    constant = 100, 
    color = "#BCD8CD"

var nodes = [
    {label: '1st stage', x:   constant, y: 215 , width:70,height:50 , color :color , stage: true },
    {label: '2nd stage', x: constant + 150 , y: 215 ,width:70,height:50 ,color :color, stage: true },
    {label: '3rd stage', x: constant + 279, y: 215 ,width:70,height:50, color :color, stage: false },
    {label: '4th stage', x: constant + 460, y: 215 ,width:70,height:50, color :color, stage: false },
    {label: '5th stage', x: constant + 660, y: 215 ,width:70,height:50 ,color :color, stage: false },
    {label: '6th stage', x: constant + 350, y: 350 ,width:70,height:50, color :color, stage: true }
];

var links = [
    { source: 0, target: 1 },
    { source: 1, target: 2},
    { source: 2, target: 3},
    { source: 3, target: 4},
    { source: 1, target: 5}
];

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

var marker = svg.append('marker')
    .attr('id',"triangle")
    .attr('viewBox',"0 0 10 10")
    .attr('refX',"0")
    .attr('refY',"5")
    .attr('markerUnits','strokeWidth')
    .attr('markerWidth','4')
    .attr('markerHeight','3')
    .attr('orient','auto')

var path = marker.append('path')
      .attr('d',"M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z")

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links);
force.linkDistance(width/4);

var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr("stroke-width", "2")
    .attr('marker-end','url(#triangle)')
    .attr('stroke','black')

var defs = svg.append("defs");

// create filter with id #drop-shadow
// height=130% so that the shadow is not clipped
var filter = defs.append("filter")
    .attr("id", "drop-shadow")
    .attr("height", "130%");

// SourceAlpha refers to opacity of graphic that this filter will be applied to
// convolve that with a Gaussian with standard deviation 3 and store result
// in blur
filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
    .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
    .attr("stdDeviation", 3)
    .attr("result", "blur");

// translate output of Gaussian blur to the right and downwards with 2px
// store result in offsetBlur
var feOffset = filter.append("feOffset")
    .attr("in", "blur")
    .attr("dx", 2)
    .attr("dy", 2)
    .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

// overlay original SourceGraphic over translated blurred opacity by using
// feMerge filter. Order of specifying inputs is important!
var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "offsetBlur")
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
.attr("transform", function(d){
    return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")";
})

node.append("rect").attr("class", "nodeRect")
        .attr("rx", 6)
        .attr("ry", 6)
        .attr('width', function(d) { return d.width; })
        .attr('height', function(d) { return d.height; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
        .transition()
        .duration(1000) // this is 1s
        .delay(1000) 
        .style("fill",function(d){if(d.stage) return "#FF9966"})
        .style("filter",function(d){if(d.stage) return "url(#drop-shadow)"})


node.append("text").style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .style("font-weight", 900)
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", "0.3px")
        .style("font-size", "16px")
        .attr("y", function (d){return d.height/2+6;})
        .attr("x", function (d){return d.width/2;})
        .text(function (d) {return d.label;})

force.start();

link.attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x + d.source.width/2; })
    .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y + d.source.height/2; })
    .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x + d.target.width/2; })
    .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y + d.target.height/2; })
    .transition()
    .duration(1000) // this is 1s
    .delay(1000) 
    .style("filter",function(d){if(d.source.stage) return "url(#drop-shadow)"})
```

this works as expected, apart from the links that is getting rendered. For example, this link :

[image]

however I want that link to be :

[image]

How can I achieve this in d3?

Comment: You can use [d3.svg.line](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line) for that.

Comment: c'mon, batman, I'm working my butt off here... I answered your question no? ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idiomatic way is to use a `path` element instead of a `line` and use `d3.svg.line()` to create the links.  This way the arrows work also and it is completely and easily animatable.

---

### Notes

While working with this (very interesting!) example, I found a couple of systemic issues...

1. **[Bug in IE](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/781964/)**
   Apparently MS can't be bothered fixing this, but there is a problem with rendering elements with markers on them.  The [work-arround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17421050/2670182) for this is to insert the path on its parent and that is the purpose of this line in the force ontick event handler...
   `link.each(function() {this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this); });`
2. **Problem with filter clipping**
   In the example we have path element instructions like this `d="M28,46L28,23L77,23"` to render two orthogonal lines.  This works fine with the filter and the drop shadow is rendered as expected, but, as the node is dragged such that the length of one of the lines is shorter than the corresponding dimension of the marker, a problem emerges: the path element, including the marker, start to get clipped by the filter.
   I don't understand what's going on exactly, but it seems that the bounding box for the filter, which is a percentage of the path bounding box, collapses to zero height and this somehow clips the referencing path element.  As soon as the path bounding box becomes zero, the problem disappears (at least it does in Chrome and Opera...).

[image]

As part of my attempts to manage the above problems, I tried to limit all of the numbers in the path elements to be integers and this was implemented by adding a quantiser getter to the node data with this code...

```
 force.nodes().forEach(function(d) {
    d.q = {};
    Object.keys(d).forEach(function (p) {
      if (!isNaN(d[p])) Object.defineProperty(d.q, p, {
        get: function () {
          return Math.round(d[p])
        }
      });
    })
  });
```

This creates a `q` object on each node datum with a getter for any member that returns a numeric value - I don't need to think about which ones, so I just hit them all - and that allows me to do this, for example...

```
  node.attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + d.q.x + "," + d.q.y + ")";
  })
```

So, `d.q.x` and `d.q.y` are rounded versions of `d.x` and `d.y`. 
I was intending to use this in the `linkPath` function as well to make all of the numbers in the path `d` attribute integers, but I realised that this was better achieved with custom `x` and `y` accessors in the `d3.svg.line()` object here...

```
  var connector = d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear")
    .x(function(d){return Math.round(d[0])})
    .y(function(d){return Math.round(d[1])});
  function linkPath(d){
    var  h1 = d.source.height, w1 = d.source.width, x1 = d.source.x + w1/2, y1 = d.source.y + h1/2,
      h2 = d.target.height, w2 = d.target.width, x2 = d.target.x  - markerW - 4, y2 = d.target.y + h2/2;
      return connector([[x1, y1], [x1, y2], [x2, y2]]);
  }
```

The function returned by `d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear")` accepts an array of points in the form of `[[p1x, p1y], [p2x, p2y], ... ]` and uses the provided, standard interpolator to construct a string value for the path `d` attribute,  (It's also fun to try other, standard d3 interpolator functions like basis for example).  By adding the custom accessors, all of the coordinates provided are assured to be rounded to the nearest integer value.
The function `linkPath`, which is called in the force tick callback, simply constructs an array of three points based on the link data and passes that array to the `connector` function and returns a string that can be used as the `d` attribute of a `path` element.  The call signature assures that it is passed a copy of the bound datum for each element...

```
link.attr("d", linkPath);
```

So, the data bound to each link is used to create three points, which are interpolated and rendered as a path.

---

### Working code

There are a few issues that need to be managed to ensure the connectors and the arrowheads work properly but these are not really relevant here so I didn't clutter up the code with fixes...

```js
  var width = 600,
    height = 148,
    constant = 10,
    color = "#BCD8CD"

  var scale = .75, w = 70*scale, h = 50*scale,
    nodes = [
    {label: '1st stage', x:   constant, y: 20*scale , width:w,height:h , color :color , stage: true },
    {label: '2nd stage', x: constant + 150*scale , y: 20*scale ,width:w,height:h ,color :color, stage: true },
    {label: '3rd stage', x: constant + 279*scale, y: 20*scale ,width:w,height:h, color :color, stage: false },
    {label: '4th stage', x: constant + 460*scale, y: 20*scale ,width:w,height:h, color :color, stage: false },
    {label: '5th stage', x: constant + 660*scale, y: 20*scale ,width:w,height:h ,color :color, stage: false },
    {label: '6th stage', x: constant + 350*scale, y: 100*scale ,width:w,height:h, color :color, stage: true }
    ].map(function(d, i){return (d.fixed = (i != 5), d)});

  var links = [
    { source: 0, target: 1 },
    { source: 1, target: 2},
    { source: 2, target: 3},
    { source: 3, target: 4},
    { source: 1, target: 5}
  ];

  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

  var markerW = 4, markerH = 3,
    marker = svg.append('marker')
    .attr('id',"triangle")
    .attr('viewBox',"0 0 10 10")
    .attr('refX',"0")
    .attr('refY',5)
    .attr('markerUnits','strokeWidth')
    .attr('markerWidth',markerW)
    .attr('markerHeight',markerH)
    .attr('orient','auto')

  var path = marker.append('path')
    .attr('d',"M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z")

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .linkDistance(width/4)
    .on("tick", function(e){
      //hack to force IE to do it's job!
      link.each(function() {this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this); });

      link.attr("d", linkPath);
      node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.q.x + "," + d.q.y + ")";
      })
    });
    force.nodes().forEach(function(d) {
      d.q = {};
      Object.keys(d).forEach(function (p) {
        if (!isNaN(d[p])) Object.defineProperty(d.q, p, {
          get: function () {
            return Math.round(d[p])
          }
        });
      })
    });

  var connector = d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear")
    .x(function(d){return Math.round(d[0])})
    .y(function(d){return Math.round(d[1])});
  function linkPath(d){
    return connector([[d.source.x + d.source.width/2, d.source.y + d.source.height/2],
      [d.source.x + d.source.width/2, d.target.y + d.target.height/2],
      [d.target.x  - markerW - 4, d.target.y + d.target.height/2]]);
  }

  var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr("stroke-width", "2")
    .attr('marker-end','url(#triangle)')
    .attr('stroke','black')
    .attr("fill", "none");

  var defs = svg.append("defs");

  // create filter with id #drop-shadow
  // height=130% so that the shadow is not clipped
  var filter = defs.append("filter")
    .attr("id", "drop-shadow")
    .attr({"height": "200%", "width": "200%", x: "-50%", y: "-50%"});

  // SourceAlpha refers to opacity of graphic that this filter will be applied to
  // convolve that with a Gaussian with standard deviation 3 and store result
  // in blur
  filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
    .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
    .attr("stdDeviation", 3)
    .attr("result", "blur");

  // translate output of Gaussian blur to the right and downwards with 2px
  // store result in offsetBlur
  var feOffset = filter.append("feOffset")
    .attr("in", "blur")
    .attr("dx", 2)
    .attr("dy", 2)
    .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

  // overlay original SourceGraphic over translated blurred opacity by using
  // feMerge filter. Order of specifying inputs is important!
  var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

  feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "offsetBlur")
  feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

  var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr("transform", function(d){
      return "translate("+ d.q.x+","+ d.q.y+")";
    })
  .call(force.drag)

  node.append("rect").attr("class", "nodeRect")
    .attr("rx", 6)
    .attr("ry", 6)
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.width; })
    .attr('height', function(d) { return d.height; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
    .transition()
    .duration(1000) // this is 1s
    .delay(1000)
    .style("fill",function(d){if(d.stage) return "#FF9966"})
    .style("filter",function(d){if(d.stage) return "url(#drop-shadow)"})


  node.append("text").style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .style("font-weight", 900)
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .style("stroke-width", "0.3px")
    .style("font-size", 16*scale + "px")
    .attr("y", function (d){return d.height/2+6*scale;})
    .attr("x", function (d){return d.width/2;})
    .text(function (d) {return d.label;})

  force.start();

    link.attr("d", linkPath)
   .transition()
    .duration(1000) // this is 1s
    .delay(1000)
    .style("filter",function(d){if(d.source.stage) return "url(#drop-shadow)"});

  d3.select("svg").append("text").attr({"y": height - 20, fill: "black"}).text("drag me!")
```

```css
svg { overflow: visible;}
.node {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
.link {
  stroke: #777;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
g.hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is brilliant ! I want to know what these lines does `   force.nodes().forEach(function(d) {
      d.q = {};
      Object.keys(d).forEach(function (p) {
        if (!isNaN(d[p])) Object.defineProperty(d.q, p, {
          get: function () {
            return Math.round(d[p])
          }
        });
      })
    });`

Comment: and also `var connector = d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear")
    .x(function(d){return Math.round(d[0])})
    .y(function(d){return Math.round(d[1])});
  function linkPath(d){
    return connector([[d.source.x + d.source.width/2, d.source.y + d.source.height/2],
      [d.source.x + d.source.width/2, d.target.y + d.target.height/2],
      [d.target.x  - markerW - 4, d.target.y + d.target.height/2]]);
  }`

Comment: @batman: cheers. I added some text to the post that attempt to answer your comments... Please let me know if it's still not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around solution by creating an empty label:

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gj2y87z8/14/)

```
var nodes = [
    {label: '1st stage', x:   constant, y: 215 , width:70,height:50 , color :color , stage: true },
    {label: '2nd stage', x: constant + 150 , y: 215 ,width:70,height:50 ,color :color, stage: true },
    {label: '3rd stage', x: constant + 279, y: 215 ,width:70,height:50, color :color, stage: false },
    {label: '4th stage', x: constant + 460, y: 215 ,width:70,height:50, color :color, stage: false },
    {label: '5th stage', x: constant + 660, y: 215 ,width:70,height:50 ,color :color, stage: false },
    {label: '', x: constant + 185, y: 370 ,width:0,height:0 ,color :color, stage: true },
    {label: '6th stage', x: constant + 350, y: 350 ,width:70,height:50, color :color, stage: true }
];

var links = [
    { source: 0, target: 1 },
    { source: 1, target: 2},
    { source: 2, target: 3},
    { source: 3, target: 4},
    { source: 1, target: 5},
    { source: 5, target: 6}
];
```