# The position of a line does not change in IE11 after `.attr`() update of `<path>`

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, internet-explorer-11

Using **d3**'s method `.attr` to update `<path d="M100,100L200,200" style="marker-end: url(#end-arrow)">` has no effect in IE11? If I remove `style="marker-end: url(#end-arrow)"`, it will become normal in IE11. How to get the results like Chrome display?

**Bug**: [Show in IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx1fO.png)

HTML:

```
<svg width="100%" height="300px">
  <defs>
    <marker id="end-arrow" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="50" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="5" orient="auto">
      <path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5"></path>
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <path class="link" d="M100,100L200,200" style="marker-end: url(#end-arrow)"></path>
  <circle class="start" cx="100" cy="100" r="40"/>
  <circle class="end" cx="200" cy="200" r="40"/>
</svg>
<div>
  <input name="update1" type="button" value="update1">
  <input name="update2" type="button" value="update2">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  cursor: default;
}
circle {
   stroke: black;
   stroke-width: 1;
   fill: #f3f5f6;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
d3.select('input[name=update1]').on('click', function() {
  d3.select('path.link').attr('d', 'M100,100L300,100');
  d3.select('circle.end')
    .attr('cx', '300')
    .attr('cy', '100')
})
d3.select('input[name=update2]').on('click', function() {
  d3.select('path.link').attr('d', 'M100,100L200,200');
  d3.select('circle.end')
    .attr('cx', '200')
    .attr('cy', '200')
})
```

Can you help me change the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhangyuanliang/4kqt1dr9/21/) example I wrote?

Comment: Your JSFiddle works for me in IE11. That is, as far as I cant tell, it works exactly the same in all browsers I have checked it in (Firefox, Chrome, IE11 and Edge).

Comment: @Phylogenesis The position of the line does not change in IE11, when you click button (update1 and update2).

Comment: @Phylogenesis I have just improved the content of the problem, you can help me look at it? Thank you.

Comment: Your second example also works for me in IE11. Are you sure the d3 library is loading correctly for you? It wouldn't be the first time I had seen issues with third-party JS libraries and China's great firewall.

Comment: Okay I can now see the issue. It appears the Windows 10 build of IE11 is different to the Windows 7 version.

Comment: See my changes [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4kqt1dr9/22/). Basically, it removes the style and reads it shortly afterwards in order to get IE11 to redraw it correctly.

Comment: This issue is strongly related to the one described in [*"SVG line markers not updating when line moves in IE10?"*](/q/15693178). Whereas IE 10 will move the lines but not the markers, IE 11 fails to move the lines at all in case there are markers on them, which is what you are witnessing. However, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17421050/4235784) will fix the problem for both versions of IE. https://jsfiddle.net/4kqt1dr9/23/

Comment: @Phylogenesis@altocumulus Thanks, I am very happy that the problem of tangled for several days has finally been solved. My English is not good and may bring some inconvenience. Because of your answer, I even think about when I can be as powerful as you. Thank you once again.