# D3. Js force oriented graph, where path is not compatible with ie10, ie11

Tags: d3.js, svg, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

My force-directed graph created with D3.js works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 9:
[image]

In IE 10 and IE 11 the links will not get rendered:

[image]

However, there are elements in the DOM structure representing the links, and when I change their styles once the page rendering has ended, they will eventually be displayed. But, as soon as I drag a node, the link is dead.

Have a look at the following snippet for a demo:

```js
var links = [
        {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "licensing"},
        {source: "Microsoft", target: "HTC", type: "licensing"}
    ];

    var nodes = {};

    links.forEach(function(link) {
        link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
        link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
    });

    var w = 960,
        h = 500;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
        .links(links)
        .size([w, h])
        .linkDistance(60)
        .charge(-300)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

   
    svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
        .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
        .enter().append("svg:marker")
        .attr("id", String)
        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 15)
        .attr("refY", -1.5)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 6)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
  
    var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
        .data(force.links())
        .enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
        .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });
    //circle
    var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
        .data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("r", 6)
        .call(force.drag);
    //text content
    var text = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("g")
        .data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("svg:g");

    
    text.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", 8)
        .attr("y", ".31em")
        .attr("class", "shadow")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    text.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", 8)
        .attr("y", ".31em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  
    function tick() {
        path.attr("d", function(d) {
            var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,//增量
                dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            return "M" + d.source.x + ","
                + d.source.y + "A" + dr + ","
                + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + ","
                + d.target.y;
        });

        circle.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

        text.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
    }
```

```css
path.link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #666;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        marker#licensing {
            fill: green;
        }

        path.link.licensing {
            stroke: green;
        }

        path.link.resolved {
            stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
        }

        circle {
            fill: #ccc;
            stroke: #333;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        text {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        text.shadow {
            stroke: #fff;
            stroke-width: 3px;
            stroke-opacity: .8;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>testD3-30-ArrowForce.html</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Please edit this to have a *Minimal*, Complete, Verifiable Example

Comment: Okay, I've simplified the code

Comment: Probably related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45276999/4235784 . Read my comment to that question and follow the link in that comment. There are issues in IE10 and IE11 when it comes to paths with markers. There is no real fix but some workarounds are available.

Comment: That's the solution. Thank you very much. Thank you.