# d3.select() with ID of object not work

Tags: d3.js, internet-explorer-10

```
                            // aspect ratio for resize
                        var resizeGraph = function(){
                            var ratio = scope.width  / scope.height;
                            var graphContainer = d3.select("#graph_e_p"); 
                            console.log('---->',graphContainer)
                            if(scope.width > graphContainer.style("width").replace('px','')){
                               svg.attr("width",graphContainer.style("width").replace('px',''));
                               svg.attr("height",graphContainer.style("width").replace('px','') / ratio );
                            }
                        };

                        resizeGraph(); // on load

                        d3.select(window).on('resize', function(){ // on resize
                            resizeGraph();
                        });
```

When I show on console the content of `div` variable, IE shows me nothing.

Instead on Chrome or FireFox, works fine, the element was grab from DOM correctly.
The ID is unique of course, and I try with this "[internet explorer 10 not showing svg path (d3.js graph)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588478/internet-explorer-10-not-showing-svg-path-d3-js-graph)"  but not works.

To complete the scenario, this code is execute into an angularjs directive, but I don't think that's it the problem (but maybe I'm wrong).

As I mentioned this is angularjs app, the html is a chunk of main structure, and is defined as it

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="graph_e_p">
    <directive-name data="data"
                 w="600"
                 h="400"
                 resize="true"
            >
    </directive-name>
</div>
```

Of course, bootstrap 3.x it's here...

Given that the Chrome and FireFox grab correctly the div, maybe there is something of 'wrong' on html definition.

Did anyone has encounter this sort of problem?

Comment: Can you show us the full code please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff here it is the code, for some reason that I don't know IE not grab the div from the DOM.

Comment: And this element that you're selecting is defined where?

Comment: It's defined as directive container, directly wrote on html, it isn't created by JavaScript.