# Markers are not working in d3 in IE browser

Tags: d3.js

I tried force layout in d3. For representing direction on links, I use markers.In Chrome and FF everything is working fine.But for IE dragging nodes works but links remains constant.If I remove markers from links then links can be drag or move according to nodes.So, how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the real world: it will simply not work on IE. Just recently I made a code for a client, which performed a check: if the browser was IE, the code didn't create the markers. If the browser was != from IE, the code created the markers. Maybe I'm wrong, but this is the best advice I can give you now.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588478/internet-explorer-10-not-showing-svg-path-d3-js-graph

Comment: I really loved solution #3 in the accepted answer of the link above: *"Wait for Microsoft to fix this bug"*. Let's wait until the cows come home...