# MS Edge doesn't render lines in a 3D force directed graph

Tags: d3.js, microsoft-edge, d3-force-directed, archimate

I have a force-directed graph made using D3.js. In Firefox, Chrome and Opera everything renders fine. My problem is that MS Edge (Win10, version 44.17763.1.0) doesn't draw edges and lines, that is the only flaw - otherwise everything works (texts, nodes, arrows, movement, zoom etc.).

Event such a simple code (below) doesn't work - the red line isn't drawn:

```
  //  test 
  legend.append("line")
        .attr("x1", 0)    
        .attr("y1", 10)     
        .attr("x2", 40)     
        .attr("y2", 10)   
        .style("stroke", "red")
        .attr("class", "link");
```

Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/svorad/jc0pa8dz/1/

I already tried everything I could thought of. Any ideas?

Comment: I try to make a search about this issue and I got some information that 
IE and Edge causes paths with markers to render improperly.
If possible for you then you can avoid using markers or you can embed the markers in the path like this: http://jsfiddle.net/niaconis/3YsWY/9/ Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588478/internet-explorer-10-not-showing-svg-path-d3-js-graph